# Como carregar o ADS após todo o conteudo restante

Tags: javascript, jquery, vbulletin

Estou tentando fazer o Revive AD Server do meu site (um fórum na plataforma do Vbulletin) carregar apenas após todo o conteudo, isso porque se trata de um servidor externo, o que acaba deixando o site mais lento pois o ADS encontra-se no topo da página.

Já tentei utilizar as seguintes opções, e até 'funciona' quando mas quando começa a execução do ADS a página fica toda branca, apagando o conteúdo que já havia carregado:

```
//Código para carregar o script no header da página.
<script>
    $.getScript(url);
</script>

//Código para chamar o script no block em que é encaixado o ADS no site.
$(window).bind("load", function() {
```

O código completo que chama o banner do ADS é parecido o esse:

```
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://site.com.br'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type='text/javascript'><!--//<![CDATA[
        var m3_u = (location.protocol=='https:'?'https://site.com.br':'http://site.com.br');
        var m3_r = Math.floor(Math.random()*99999999999);
        if (!document.MAX_used) document.MAX_used = ',';
        document.write ("<scr"+"ipt type='text/javascript' src='"+m3_u);
        document.write ("?zone=zone");
        document.write ('&amp;cb=' + m3_r);
        if (document.MAX_used != ',') document.write ("&amp;exclude=" + document.MAX_used);
        document.write (document.charset ? '&amp;charset='+document.charset : (document.characterSet ? '&amp;charset='+document.characterSet : ''));
        document.write ("&amp;loc=" + escape(window.location));
        if (document.referrer) document.write ("&amp;referer=" + escape(document.referrer));
        if (document.context) document.write ("&context=" + escape(document.context));
        if (document.mmm_fo) document.write ("&amp;mmm_fo=1");
        document.write ("'><\/scr"+"ipt>");
    //]]>--></script>
    <noscript>
        <a href='http://site.com.br' target='_blank'>
            <img src='http://site.com.br' border='0' alt='' />
        </a>
    </noscript>
</body>
```

Comment: window.onload = function() {
    //código aqui
}

Comment: Tentei e deu o mesmo problema. O site começa a se montar normal sem o ADS, mas quando começa a carregar o conteudo do ADS a tela fica em branco.

Comment: Talvez seja algum problema no código do ads. Faz a mesma coisa, só que em um arquivo HTML limpo. Só o ads e alguma coisa dentro pra você poder notar se ele ficar branco. Se acontecer a mesma coisa, é problema com o código do ads, se não acontecer, é alguma incompatibilidade entre o ads ou window.load e o fórum, e nesse último caso, só tem como resolver "caçando" essa tal incompatibilidade.

Comment: O fato de ter um noscript no código influencia? pois estou colocando dentro do ONLOAD apenas o script js.
Reparei ao fazer o teste proposto que apenas o conteudo noscript carrega na página, por isso a pergunta.

Comment: A tag noscript é chamada apenas caso o navegador esteja com JS desabilitado.